# How can ArrayController have sublists without needing explicit itemController in {{#each sublist}}?

Tags: ember.js

This **works**:

```
{{#each basicColours itemController='colour'}}

ColoursController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  itemController: 'colour',
  numBasicColours: 5,
  basicColours: function(){
    return this.get('arrangedContent').slice(0, this.get('numBasicColours'))
  }.property('arrangedContent'),
});
```

but I would like to be able to do it without the `itemController='colour'` in the each call, in particular because that option is not looked up dynamically, ie, I cannot do `itemController=itemController`

Comment: This is probably not what you are after, but you only need to declare the itemController either in your loop _or_ in your controller. Though the above will work

Comment: The array controller does have an itemController defined, and a bare `{{#each}}` works as expected, giving an instance of `ColourController` inside the loop. However, `{{#each basicColours}}` results in the iterator `this` being a `Colour`, not a `ColourController` unless `itemController` is set explicitly. The reason for the question is that yes, I would like to only declare it in the array_controller.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is you are iterating (using each) on the basicColours computed property (not the array controller).  If you want the itemController property to apply, you need to each over the controller itself (which is what happens when you do {{#each}} (probably these as well {{#each item in this}} or {{#each item in controller}} ).

You could also just create another template and call
{{ render 'otherTemplate' basicColours}}

which would then use OtherTemplateArrayController which you could add itemController to and then the content of the controller would be your computed property.

in the template:

```
 {{ render 'otherTemplate' basicColours}}

ColoursController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
 numBasicColours: 5,
 basicColours: function(){
   return this.get('arrangedContent').slice(0, this.get('numBasicColours'))
 }.property('arrangedContent'),
});

OtherTemplateArrayController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  itemController: 'colour'
});
```